# Weird bug - can't put a regular blockquote between two spoilers

Tags: support, spoilers, markdown

In a recent question of mine, I encountered what I think is a bug when I tried to put a regular blockquote between two spoilers:

Text:

> !This is spoiler 1.
>
> "This is the regular blockquote".
>
> !This is spoiler #2.

As you can see, it renders everything as one big blockquote as well as the exclamation points that are supposed to make something a "Spoiler".  Trying to make the middle  blockquote into a spoiler, resulting in three sooilers in a row, also fails.

> !Spoiler 1
>
> !Spoiler 2
>
> !Spoiler 3

It happens on both the mobile site and the full site.

Comment: Spoiler blocks aren't fully implemented by design so you'll find a lot of strange goings on with them.

Answer (score 8):

> This is spoiler 1.

> "This is the regular blockquote".

> This is spoiler #2.

Is this what you want?

Code for the above:

```
>!This is spoiler 1.

<!>

>"This is the regular blockquote".

<!>

>!This is spoiler #2.
```

Comment: @Spencer I just put a non-displayed entity in between, such as  <!>

Comment: @Alex I remember once someone on Main Meta got quite annoyed at me for doing that; this kind of stuff seems to be frowned upon.

Comment: @Stormblessed Why?

Comment: @Alex I don’t know, ask Sonic the Anonymous whatever.

Comment: @Stormblessed Just because Sonic doesn't like something, doesn't mean it's "frowned upon" in general.

Comment: @Spencer I've edited Alex's answer to add the code for how it was produced.

Comment: Looking at the emitted HTML, those <!> thingies seem to be producing empty <p> tags, which is semantically incorrect since a "paragraph" should contain text (but I'm really surprised that anyone would notice or care). I suppose a screen reader might mishandle them, but honestly, I'd expect them to either skip it or just say "paragraph no text" or something like that.

Comment: @RandAlThor Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe it should be something like <!/> then.

Comment: @Stormblessed Also, if there's a specific discussion on 'main' or 'meta' then, try to link to it, otherwise it sounds like people's opinions and we'll simply ignore it.

Comment: You can also use a HTML comment `<!-- -->` which will not be translated into anything.

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of CommonMark this is now even easier to do, just use the following markdown:

```
>!This is spoiler 1.

>"This is the regular blockquote".

>!This is spoiler #2.
```

For the rendered output:

> This is spoiler 1.

> "This is the regular blockquote".

> This is spoiler #2.

Continous spoilers still don't work, I don't think that has ever really been supported, but you can force it yourself like:

```
>!Spoiler 1
>! <br/><br/>
>!Spoiler 2
>! <br/><br/>
>!Spoiler 3
```

For:

> Spoiler 1
>  
> Spoiler 2
>  
> Spoiler 3

Comment: Instead of fancy HTML tags (which the non-coders among us might not be familiar with), an easier method is simply to put two spaces at the end of each line within a continuous spoilerblock.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Good point didn't think about two spaces on the empty lines too